# Video not playing on mobile devices in React

Tags: reactjs, iphone, ipad, html5-video, mobile-safari

The video is playing properly on any desktop or laptop, but when on mobile, specifically mobile Safari, the video is not playing. However the video is showing as an element with the correct styling. I have applied the `playsInline` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` solutions, but cannot get the video to play. The video is also 3.3mb and in the assets folder. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the video to show and autoplay on mobile?

JSX:

```
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
                <video
                  loop
                  muted={true}
                  autoPlay
                  playsInline={true}
                  id="video"
                >
                <source autoPlay muted={true} src="${video}" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>`,
              }}
            />
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters but it's `autoplay` not `autoPlay` same for `playsinline`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: @nlta In React I believe that that `autoPlay` and `playsInline` are camel-cased

Comment: Get a tool like **MediaInfo** to check the a/v codecs of your MP4 file. Also some media players like VLC can tell you about the MP4's codecs. Apple expects MP4 containing H.264 video codec with AAC audio codec. Also make sure you're testing on a device that can handle those codecs. Test [this MP4](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) which has basic codec settings, does it play for you on Safari? Tell us your MP4's codecs and what device / operating system (version) you're testing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved The Issue!**

I checked the original mp4 codecs and it was AAC, H.264. I used HandBrake to decode the mp4 file and took the audio out as well. I am not too sure if the muted function was working correctly, but decoding the file seemed to do the trick.